# trying to change string in a list in python via method and loop

Tags: python, string, list

```
magician_names=('joker','Randell Flag','Bozo')
    def show_magicians(names):
        for i in names:
            print(i)
    def make_great(names):
        names[:] = ['the great '+str(names[i]) for i in names]
    make_great(magician_names)
    show_magicians(magician_names)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tuples are immutable. Use a list instead.

Comment: `magician_names` is _not_ a list, but a tuple. However, `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`, so it's _not_ possible to use `names[:] = ...` on a tuple and thus "change string in a [tuple] via method and loop"

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this :

```
def make_great(names):
    new_list=[]
    var = ['the great '+str(names[i]) for i in range(len(names))]
    new_list.append(var)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to return a tuple, maybe something like this could help. Like previous people have said, it would be good if you were more elaborate on your question as it is difficult to guess what you are asking.

```
def make_great(names):
    names = tuple([f'the great {str(i)}' for i in names])
    return names
```

Answer (score -1):

This would fix your code

```
magician_names=('joker','Randell Flag','Bozo')
def show_magicians(names):
    for i in names:
        print(i)
def make_great(names):
    names = [f'the great {i}' for i in names]
    print(names)
make_great(magician_names)
show_magicians(magician_names)
```

Your mistake was over here:

```
names[:] = ['the great '+str(names[i]) for i in names]
```

i is already a string so you were calling a list using a string as its index.